# A more efficient MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql which works, but I can't help thinking there's a better way of doing it?

```
SELECT u.username, count( c.username ) AS intImageCount
FROM users u
JOIN content c ON c.username = u.username
WHERE (SELECT count( username )FROM content WHERE username = c.username) > 0
GROUP BY u.username
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I don't have the subquery, how do I only bring back users which have enteries in content c?

Comment: That's the default behavior of an (INNER) JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see the need for the subselect and use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT u.username, count( c.username ) AS intImageCount
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN content c ON c.username = u.username
GROUP BY u.username
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `HAVING` rather

Something like

```
SELECT u.username, count( c.username ) AS intImageCount 
FROM users u 
JOIN content c ON c.username = u.username 
GROUP BY u.username
HAVING count( c.username ) > 0
```

Have a look at [SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Comment: It's inner join, even HAVING should not be needed, as only rows with matching username are selected.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of HAVING, your mere [(INNER) JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) already does the trick.
You can drop the subquery altogether.

```
SELECT   u.username
         , count( c.username ) AS intImageCount
FROM     users u
         INNER JOIN content c ON c.username = u.username
GROUP BY u.username
```